# Supremum of integrable random variables and compact convergence

Tags: integration, probability-theory, uniform-convergence

Edit: @saz answered the original question so I modified it to use compact convergence (uniform convergence on all compacts sets) instead to see if it still holds.

Suppose:

$\cdot$ $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is an integrable random variable

$\cdot$ Continuous functions $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ and $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ are such that $f(X)$ and $f_n(X)$ is integrable for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$

$\cdot$ $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f_n(x) < \infty$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$

$\cdot$  $f_n$ converges to $f$ compactly as $n\to\infty$.

Does it hold that $\sup_{i\in\mathbb{N}} f_n(X)$ is integrable?

What I know so far:
$$
\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n(X)| \leq f(X) + \sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n(X) - f(X)|
$$
So if $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n(X) - f(X)|$ is integrable, then $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n(X)|$ is also integrable. But how do I show $\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |f_n(X) - f(X)|$ is integrable?

Comment: Well, if $f_n \to f$ uniformly, then  $$\|f_n-f\|_{\infty} := \sup_x |f_n(x)-f(x)| \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty}  0$$ and so $$M:=\sup_n \|f_n-f\|_{\infty} < \infty.$$ This implies $$\sup_n |f_n(X)-f(X)| \leq M$$ for any random variable $X$ and the right-hand side is trivially integrable.

Comment: @saz: Thank you. I understand now.

Comment: I've modified the question to use compact convergence instead of uniform convergence. Thank you @saz for your answer to the original question.